# error handling with imaplib in python

Tags: python, error-handling, imaplib

When I use this line:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4("some host")
```

I get this error:

```
 m = imaplib.IMAP4("some host")
  File "C:\Python25\lib\imaplib.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\imaplib.py", line 230, in open
    self.sock.connect((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
error: (10061, 'Connection refused')
```

How would I do error handling for this error?

Comment: A blind way to fix this is to try using imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(), if it's not working you will have to give us more information about the imap server that you try to connect to; opened ports ...

Comment: @singularity I know why I am getting the error and the fix, just didn't know how to raise an exception for this case. I was trying to use imaplib.IMAP4.error, which Adam pointed out that I needed to use socket.error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a standard `try/except` block:

```
import socket

try:
    m = imaplib.IMAP4("some host")
except socket.error, e:
    print "Error opening IMAP connection: ", e
```